# Error using portfolio.optim

Tags: r, finance

I am currently trying to fix an error within a portfolio optimization program. I am attempting to create a variable which contains the standard deviation of the optimal portfolio for all possible expected returns within a range of the minimum expected return and maximum expected return of a given set of securities.

The following chunk produces a sequence of values from the minimum expected return to the maximum expected return.

```
er_vals <- seq(from = min(df_table$er), to = max(df_table$er), length.out = 1000)
er_vals
```

The following chunk is supposed to create a variable which contains corresponding standard deviations for the optimal portfolio with a desired expected portfolio return of er. However, for some reason I have been receiving the error

```
sd_vals <- sapply(er_vals, function(er) {
  op <- portfolio.optim(as.matrix(df), pm=er)
  return(op$ps)
})
sd_vals

Error in solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec = b0, meq = 2) : 
  constraints are inconsistent, no solution!
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!